# vueapexcharts number of series

Tags: javascript, vue.js, apexcharts

I took an example of `vueapexcharts` to implement in my application, it comes by default with `4 series`, but when trying to include new series, an error occurs and the chart is not painted, see the original example:

```
<apexchart v-if="sales_donut_options" height="460" type="donut" :options="sales_donut_options" :series="values_lics"></apexchart>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueApexCharts from 'vue-apexcharts';
Vue.use(VueApexCharts);
Vue.component('apexchart', VueApexCharts);
import '@/assets/sass/widgets/widgets.scss';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      values_lics: [1111, 2222, 3333, 4444],
      labels_lics: ['1111', '2222', '3333', '4444'],
    };
  },
  computed: {
    sales_donut_options() {
      const is_dark = this.$store.state.is_dark_mode;
      let option = {
        chart: {},
        dataLabels: { enabled: false },
        expandOnClick: is_dark ? false : true,
        stroke: { show: true, width: 20, colors: is_dark ? '#0e1726' : '#fff' },
        colors: is_dark ? ['#5c1ac3', '#e2a03f', '#e7515a', '#eea033'] : ['#e2a03f', '#5c1ac3', '#e7515a', '#a64d79'],
        legend: {
          position: 'bottom',
          horizontalAlign: 'center',
          fontSize: '14px',
          markers: { width: 10, height: 10 },
          height: 50,
          offsetY: 20,
          itemMargin: { horizontal: 8, vertical: 0 },
        },
        plotOptions: {
          pie: {
            donut: {
              size: '65%',
              background: 'transparent',
              labels: {
                show: true,
                name: { show: true, fontSize: '29px', fontFamily: 'Nunito, sans-serif', offsetY: -10 },
                value: {
                  show: true,
                  fontSize: '26px',
                  fontFamily: 'Nunito, sans-serif',
                  color: is_dark ? '#bfc9d4' : undefined,
                  offsetY: 16,
                  formatter: function (val) {
                    return val;
                  },
                },
                total: {
                  show: true,
                  label: 'Total',
                  color: '#888ea8',
                  fontSize: '29px',
                  formatter: function (w) {
                    return w.globals.seriesTotals.reduce(function (a, b) {
                      return a + b;
                    }, 0);
                  },
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
        labels: this.labels_lics,
      };

      if (is_dark) {
        option['states'] = {
          hover: { filter: { type: 'none' } },
          active: { filter: { type: 'none' } },
        };
      }

      return option;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

so far it works perfectly, but if I include new values and labels, such as:

```
  values_lics: [1111, 2222, 3333, 4444, 5555, 6666],
  labels_lics: ['1111', '2222', '3333', '4444', '5555', '66666'],
```

error occurs:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: t.push is not a function
    at t.value (apexcharts.min.js?3d1e:6:1)
    at eval (apexcharts.min.js?3d1e:6:1)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at t.value (apexcharts.min.js?3d1e:6:1)
    at t.value (apexcharts.min.js?3d1e:6:1)
    at t.value (apexcharts.min.js?3d1e:14:1)
    at t.eval (apexcharts.min.js?3d1e:6:1)
    at eval (apexcharts.min.js?3d1e:14:1)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at t.value (apexcharts.min.js?3d1e:14:1)
```

Looking at the code I didn't find anything that was limiting in 4 series, why when adding new values does this error occur? where am i wrong?
I'm doing the test with fixed values, but the values will come from an API, so the number of series can be variable, 1,2,3 or 10
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, looks like stroke colors should be array not string.

Cahnge this

```
colors: is_dark ? '#0e1726' : '#fff'
```

to

```
colors: is_dark ? ['#0e1726'] : ['#fff']
```